# Tensor reshaping: Can not squeeze dim[1]

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I wanted to load a dataset via `tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor`. Problem is the dimensions aren´t correct for further processing. How can I reshape it to have the correct shape/dimension?

code:

```py
x = tfio.audio.AudioIOTensor(
    filename, dtype=None
)

audio = x.to_tensor()

tensor = tf.squeeze(audio, axis=[-1])
```

this is how the tensor looks like:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2681856, 2), dtype=int16, numpy=
array([[-979, 2163],
       [ -25, 2153],
       [1094, 2148],
       ...,
       [-383, 2107],
       [ 758, 2104],
       [1698, 2109]], dtype=int16)>
```

output:

```
Can not squeeze dim[1], expected a dimension of 1, got 2 [Op:Squeeze]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) removes dimensions of size 1 from the shape of a tensor. But this tensor have size 2 which is causing the above error. You can use [tf.reshape()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) or below code to reshape the tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.random.uniform([2681856, 2])
print(a.shape)
```

Output: `(2681856, 2)`

```
b=a[:,1]
print(b.shape)
c= a[1]
print(c.shape)
```

Output:

```
(2681856,)
(2,)
```